# Convergence of the Gaussian integral on $\mathcal{E}'$ for a mapping supported on $L^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $F : L^2(S^1) \to L^2(S^1)$ be a (nonlinear) mapping such that
\begin{equation}
\lVert F(f) \rVert \leq \lVert f \rVert
\end{equation}
for all $f \in L^2(S^1)$. For the space of smooth periodic functions $\mathcal{E}(S^1)$, we know that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}(S^1) \subset L^2(S^1) \subset \mathcal{E}'(S^1).
\end{equation}

By the Minlos theorem, there exists a unique Gaussian measure $d\mu$ on $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$ such that
\begin{equation}
e^{-\lVert f \rVert^2}=\int_{\mathcal{E}'(S^1)}e^{iT(f)} d\mu(T)
\end{equation}
for all $f \in \mathcal{E}(S^1)$.

Let $P_N$ be the projection mapping defined by
\begin{equation}
(P_N g)(x):=\sum_{k=-N}^N e^{2\pi ikx}\int_{-1}^1 g(y) e^{-2\pi iky} dy
\end{equation}
for $g \in L^2(S^1)$. Then, $P_N$ may be extended to $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$ by dual pairing.

It is clear that for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_N:=\int_{\mathcal{E}'(S^1)} F\bigl(P_N T \bigr) d\mu(T)
\end{equation}
is an well-defined element of $L^2(S^1)$ due to the above assumption for $F$.

Now, if we set $F(T)=0$ for $T \in \mathcal{E}'(S^1)- L^2(S^1)$, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}:=\int_{\mathcal{E}'(S^1)} F(T) d\mu(T)= \int_{L^2(S^1)} F(f) d\mu(f) \in L^2(S^1).
\end{equation}

My question is:

Does $\mathcal{F}_N$ converges to $\mathcal{F}$ in any sense as $N \to \infty$?

This seems like quite a nontrivial problem...Could anyone please help me?

In a previous question

[The Fourier projection mappings $\{ P_N \}$ form an equicontinuous family of linear maps on $E'(S^1)$ as well?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456556/the-fourier-projection-mappings-p-n-form-an-equicontinuous-family-of-lin?noredirect=1#comment1182602_456556),

I was answered that $\{ P_N \}$ is equicontinuous even on $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$. But I cannot see how to use this fact..