# Infinite dimensional version of the Laplace transform and Gaussian integrals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, laplace-transform

This question is somehow related to my previous one [Convergence of the Gaussian integral on $\mathcal{E}'$ for a mapping supported on $L^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457008/convergence-of-the-gaussian-integral-on-mathcale-for-a-mapping-supported-o)

Let $F : L^2(S^1) \to L^2(S^1)$ be a (nonlinear) Borel-measurable mapping such that
\begin{equation}
\lVert F(f) \rVert \leq \lVert f \rVert
\end{equation}
for all $f \in L^2(S^1)$. For the space of smooth periodic functions $\mathcal{E}(S^1)$, we know that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}(S^1) \subset L^2(S^1) \subset \mathcal{E}'(S^1).
\end{equation}

By the Minlos theorem, there exists a unique Gaussian measure $d\mu_{\alpha}$ on $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$ such that
\begin{equation}
e^{-\alpha \lVert f \rVert^2}=\int_{\mathcal{E}'(S^1)}e^{iT(f)} d\mu_{\alpha}(T)
\end{equation}
for all $f \in \mathcal{E}(S^1)$ and any fixed $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$.

Now, let us set $F=0$ on $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)- L^2(S^1)$ but suppose that $F(f)+F(-f)$ is NONZERO as an element of $L^2(S^1)$ for each $f \in L^2(S^1)-\{0\}$.

Then, I wonder if there exists some $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{E}'(S^1)} \bigl[ F(T)+F(-T) \bigr]d\mu_{\alpha}(T)=\int_{L^2(S^1)} \bigl[F(f)+F(-f) \bigr]d\mu_{\alpha}(f) \neq 0
\end{equation}
as an element of $L^2(S^1)$.

This seems related to the Laplace transform in infinite dimensions and I already posted a finite-dimensional version of the same question on ME:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794434/if-fx-neq-0-on-0-infty-does-there-exists-some-alpha-in-0-infty/4794439?noredirect=1#comment10194709_4794439

Could anyone please help me?